# How filter event based on a value?

Tags: solidity, events

I have this solidity event :

```
 event ValidateData(
       address professorAddr,
       address studentAddr,
       bytes32 data
    );
```

in Javascript I want watch the event only when the professorAddr belongs to me. 
so I did:

```
    const skillsEvent = Coursetro.ValidateData({professorAddr: "0xad170bb838d6bb3cc35bc3e278f3d44852f3470a"});
  skillsEvent.watch(function(error, result){
        if (!error)
        {
            console.log(result.args);
        } else {

            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

but I receive all events even the professorAddr is different to the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to receive only the event log related to `professorAddr` you must specify the indexed in event. Please See below:

```
event ValidateData(  
       address indexed professorAddr,  
       address studentAddr,  
       bytes32 data  
    );
```

so adding **indexed** before eventType should fix it. You have to limit of maximum **3 indexed** arguments per event in web3js 1.0. And also be sure that you are using web3js1.0 and above.

Comment: this could not be done with web3 0.2?

Comment: It must be in  ^1.0 .

Comment: it works for web3 0.20

Comment: Thank your for checking instantly. For further more please see  https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1186  and    https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/535